# Connecting a remote client to an openVPN server running on Ubuntu

Tags: server, openvpn, routing, subnet

I am really stuck on this one - please help.
I have an openVPN server running on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have a Macbook running as a client.

The Macbook connects to the VPN server without problems if it does it through the same ADSL router using the Ubuntu ip 10.0.0.3.

If I try connecting through an alternative network connection - say an iPhone hotspot I can't connect.

Logically, the Macbook client needs to know how to connect to the VPN server if it is not connecting through the same LAN as the server.
How do I achieve this? How can the Macbook "find" the VPN server if its not on the same DSL router

Comment: This seems like a basic networking question, not Ubuntu-related. 10.* addresses are non-routable: They only work when both machines are on the same LAN already. Your client must connect to the public IP address (the router), and Port Forward that connection (it's a setting on the router) to the OpenVPN server.

Answer (score 0):

True it is a networking issue but it stopped me using the openVPN server on my Ubuntu system. Resolved as follows:
In the end the answer was simple - my lack of knowledge on networking!
All that was required was to set-up port forwarding on the DSL router - in my case I am using an old Netgear router - so I had to set-up a service for the port (1194) and then change the firewall rules to allow that service. 
It should be easier on a more modern Router
hope this helps others stuck on the same issue